# successives operations with C++

Tags: c++, conditional-statements

How can I perform this code:

```
if a number n is divisible by 3, add 4 to n;
if n is not divisible by 3 but by 4, divise n by 2;
if n is not divisible by 3, not by 4, make n=n-1.
```

The problem with me is that I don't know how to make this successively. For example:
with the number 6, I have to have:

6, 10, 9, 13, 12, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1 et 0

6+4=10; 10-1=9; 9+4=13; 13-1=12; 12+4=16; 16/2=8.....0

This makes 10 operations.

So my program has to return: 6---10

Thank you for help

Comment: Grab a good C++ book, learn about control flow and the other basic stuff and ask about specific problems. That might help.

Comment: To do this multiple times, use a *loop*.  Probably a *while loop* is what you want...

Comment: So you have to do the FizzBuzz test in an interview? http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FizzBuzzTest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must loop using @jubjub's code, until the series hits 0, counting how many times through the loop:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cmath> // pour exp() 
using namespace std; 
int main() 
{ 
    for (int n=0; n<9; ++n)
    { 
        int count = 0, next = n;
        while (next != 0 && count >= 0) 
        {
            if (next % 3 == 0) 
                next += 4;
            else if (next % 4 == 0) 
                next /= 2;
            else 
                next --;
            count ++;
        }
        if (count < 0) 
            cout << "n=" << n << ": could not converge to 0" << endl;
        else
            cout << "n=" << n << ": required " << count << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know for this specific series if there is a proof that it will always converge to zero in fewer than some number of steps that depends on n. But I have included a guard in case "count" wraps around to negative numbers.

Comment: That's it..thx for ur help;

this function do the excepted work..

#include <iostream>

#include <cmath>    // pour exp()

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 int weirdSeries(int n);

 int n;

 for(int n(0);n<9;++n){

  cout<<weirdSeries(n)<<endl ;
 }
 
return 0;
}

but if i want do it without function!!!
thx a lot :D

Comment: @TayebGhagha You're getting pretty specific there, but I edited so no function. Please, look at each answer and vote up the ones you find useful, and mark one as accepted if it  (come close enough to) answers your question.

Comment: int n0,n;
for(int n0(1);n0<=10 && debut<=1;++n0){
 n=n0;
 int count = 0;
    while (n!=0 && count >= 0) 
    {
        if (n % 3 == 0) 
             n+=4;
        else if (n % 4 == 0) 
             n /=2;
        else 
             n--;
        count ++;
    }
    cout<<n0<<"-->"<<count<<endl ;
}
 
  return 0;
}

Comment: @TayebGhagha indeed, fixed. Note that iteration is safer in your case than recursion; for some n's, you will run out of stack.

Answer (score 3):

Using the modulo operator (%), you can calculate the remainder of a division. This is usually how a program decides if *n* is divisible by *f*.

```
iterations = 0;
while (n != 0) {
    if (n % 3 == 0) n+=4;
    else if (n % 4 == 0) n /=2;
    else n--;
    iterations++
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a recursive approach:

```
int num_ops(int num, int prev_ops) {
  if(num == 0) return prev_ops;

  if((num % 3) == 0)
    return num_ops(num+4, prev_ops+1);

  if((num % 4) == 0)
    return num_ops(num/2, prev_ops+1);

  else
    return num_ops(num-1, prev_ops+1);
}
```

When you first call num_ops, make sure the prev_ops argument is 0.

Comment: You should probably initialize prev_ops to 0 in your function header.

Comment: Recursion is a bad idea if you can't establish an upper bound for the recursion depth, to prove that the stack won't overflow.

Comment: What I meant was that in your current scheme, the initial call by the user has to provide a value for prev_ops.  If you change the header to read `int prev_ops = 0`, the initial call only has to provide the number they want to do operations on, without having to arbitrarily (to them) add a 0 after it.